# std::map erase wrong element

Tags: c++, stdmap

When I try to erase elements of my map, it seems to be an another element who is erased instead.
I thought it was a bad override of operator< but I don't see the problem.

```
inline bool operator<(const Etat &et){
    if (et.x < this->x){
        return false;
    }
    else if (et.x > this->x){
        return true;
    }
    if (et.y < this->y){
        return false;
    }
    else if (et.y > this->y){
        return true;
    }
    if (et.ry < this->ry){
        return false;
    }
    else if (et.ry > this->ry){
        return true;
    }
};
```

Etat constructor :

```
Etat(x, y, ry, useless, useless);
```

and the map :

```
std::map< Etat, double > map;
//The 2 last parameters of Etat are useless
map.insert(std::pair< Etat, double >(Etat(2, 2, 2, 0, 0), 0.0));
//map.size() = 1
Etat e (0, 5 ,3, 0, 0);
map.erase(e);
//map.size() = 0
//Etat(2, 2, 2) is gone
```

I don't have the problem for all instance of Etat in the map, just this case on and some others.

Test it at home :

```
#ifndef Etat_H
#define Etat_H

#include<iostream>

class Etat
{
public:
Etat(const int x, const int y, const int ry, const double vx, const double vy)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->ry = ry;
    this->vx = vx;
    this->vy = vy;
};

Etat(){};
inline bool operator==(const Etat& et){
    if (et.x == this->x && et.y == this->y && et.ry == this->ry && et.vx == this->vx && et.vy == this->vy){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
inline bool operator!=(const Etat& et){
    if (*this == et){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
inline bool operator<(const Etat &et){
    if (et.x < this->x){
        return false;
    }
    else if (et.x > this->x){
        return true;
    }
    if (et.y < this->y){
        return false;
    }
    else if (et.y > this->y){
        return true;
    }
    if (et.ry < this->ry){
        return false;
    }
    else if (et.ry > this->ry){
        return true;
    }
};

inline bool operator>(const Etat& et){
    if (*this < et){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

inline const int getX() const {
    return this->x;
};

inline const int getY() const {
    return this->y;
};

inline const int getRY() const {
    return this->ry;
};

private:
    int x, y;
    int ry;
    double vx, vy;
};

#endif // !Etat_H
```

The little piece of code can reproduce the problem :

```
std::map< Etat, double > map;
map.insert(std::pair< Etat, double >(Etat(2, 2, 2, 0, 0), 0.0));
Etat e (0, 5 ,3, 0, 0);
map.erase(e);
```

Comment: Do you really not get a [warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0454caf5304f2b86) for this code?

Comment: If the two items are equal, none of the `if` blocks match.

Comment: ya I know because it's impossible to them to be equal

Comment: @Milow So you are expecting `erase` to never, ever erase anything since no two values can *ever* compare as equal? Also, can we have enough code to replicate the problem? (In particular, I'd like to see the actual constructor body.)

Comment: Problem is that I should have Etat(2, 2, 2) and Etat(0, 5 ,3) in my map in same time, but I can't have both because they are rewrite each other.
I'm editing my post to let you try

Comment: They can only re-write each other if they evaluate as "equivalent", per [this definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map): "*Everywhere the standard library uses the [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept, **uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation**. In imprecise terms, two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`*". As `comp` is your `operator<`, this implies it is implemented wrong, returning true when it should return false, or vice versa.

Comment: Yes you're right but I can't anderstand why it is wrong. And I don't see how I can do it better

Comment: Do yourself a favor and implement `operator<` using `std::tie`. Writing `return std::tie(x, y, ry) < std::tie(et.x, et.y, et.ry);` is a lot less error prone.

Comment: @Praetorian, thanks for the tip

Comment: Given the code and values shown, I am not able to reproduce the problem. The two `Etat` values do not equate to "equivalent", and so `erase()` **IS NOT** removing the element.  However, I do see other problems in the code. The default constructor is not initialzing the fields at all. All of the operators need to be declared as `const`. `operator<` is not `return`ing any value when all the fields are exactly equal. And `operator>` is not implemented correctly (it returns true if `et` is exactly equal to `*this`, which is wrong).

Comment: Does `std::cout << map.erase(e);` result in zero or one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your class as a key in map, you must define when your elements are equal. So define comparator class:

```
struct EtatCompare {
   bool operator() (const Etat& e1, const Etat& e2) const {
       return e1.x != e2.x || e1.y != e2.y || e1.ry != e2.ry || e1.vx != e2.vx || e1.vy != e2.vy; //TODO: fill all the needed conditions here
   }
};
```

And use it creating map:

```
std::map< Etat, double, EtatCompare > map;
```

Comment: not sure to anderstand, 
x=2,  x' = 0, 
e1 < e2 : 2 < 0 => false, 
e2 < e1 : 0 < 2 => true. 
It is no false in the both case

Comment: @Anton: look at it again more carefully. Given the values shown, `(e1 < e2)` returns false (specifically, in the first `if`), but `(e2 < e1)` returns true (specifically, in the second `if`), not false like you claim.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, it's evening here :) so the problem seems to be not in operator< itself, the problem is that this operator is not used inside map at all. Map uses comparator instead. So only the last part of my answer is correct, will edit the answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks, I've edited the answer, now it should be correct.

Comment: @Anton @RemyLebeau, I just add `throw std::logic_error("error")` on the first line of `operator<` and I don't have any crash...

Comment: No, this is just a different kind of completely wrong now. The comparator for a map is supposed to be analagous to `<`, not `==`; the map determines equality using two comparator applications in opposite directions.

Comment: That's expected, because operator< is not actually used in your test code. Please check my revised answer above.

Comment: Now you're implementing a `!=` relation. That's still not `<`.

Comment: But it will be sufficient for the map! It appears to me that @Milow cannot define strong order over set of `Etat`s

Comment: @user2357112 , ya I have a debug asertion "invalid operator<"

Comment: @AntonMalyshev: No, seriously, it needs to be an ordering relation. A `!=` relation is not "sufficient for the map", and if you provide one as the comparator where the map is expecting an ordering relation, you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: @Anton you're right about the order I cannot define. Code you wrote about `operator()` doesn't work for me, it crashed on map.insert()

Comment: @Milow it works perfectly for me using clang++, just checked it adding two your test values.

Comment: `std::map< Etat, double, EtatCompare > map;
map.insert(std::pair< Etat, double >(Etat(2, 2, 2, 0, 0), 0.0));
map.insert(std::pair< Etat, double >(Etat(0, 5, 3, 0, 0), 0.0));`

Comment: @Milow also if you cannot define order over Etat values consider using unordered_map instead of map

Comment: @Anton Good idea, thanks. I'm trying to work with your code. It's almost working !

Answer (score 2):

Not all paths of your `operator<` return a value. Specifically, when `et == *this`.

If you are using C++11 or later, use [`std::tie()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) instead:

```
inline bool operator<(const Etat &rhs) const
{
    return std::tie(x, y, ry) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.ry);
}
```

You can do the same thing for your `operator==` and `operator>` implementations:

```
bool operator==(const Etat &rhs) const
{
    return std::tie(x, y, ry) == std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.ry);
}

bool operator>(const Etat &rhs) const
{
    return std::tie(x, y, ry) > std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.ry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing an

```
else {
    throw "no matching if"; // alternatively return either true or false.
}
```

Your compiler should give an warning that there is a case where there is no return.

Comment: That's right. I add this to my code but I never go to the throw